# Can I set a ceiling for above which I don't want to execute a short trade

Tags: shorting-securities

I am wondering how I can achieve the following trading order (all in one). Say that at closing yesterday a stock traded at $10. Now late at night (or early morning) outside of trading hours, I want to put an order that will short sell the stock as soon as market opens. HOWEVER, I want the short to open only above at least $9 BUT if the stock happens to open above $13, I DO NOT WANT THE ORDER TO GO THROUGH AND DON'T WANT TO OPEN A SHORT POSITION. Essentially, I want an order that will open a short sell position at market open ONLY IF $9<STOCK PRICE<$13. From my understanding, if I just place a limit order at $9, then the short position will be opened at market open as long as the price opens at $9 or above. If I place a stop limit, with the stop at $13 and limit at $9, then for the limit to be relevant, I need to stock to fall from above $13 to then below $13 - which doesn't always help me because if the stock opens at <$13, the sell order would not go through (whereas I would want it to go through as I want to open my short position as long as the stock price opens $9<x<$13). Finally, I also can't just put a limit order at $9, and then a BUY stop at $13, because that still doesn't help with the order to only execute as long as open price is $9<x<$13. How can I achieve this - limit to open short position within a range of prices only; above some set limit, BUT ALSO BELOW MY DECIDED 'CEILING'. Thanks

Comment: If your broker offers it, look at a Conditional Order

Comment: You could simply add a second order to buy at 13 - if the opening price is over 13, you are basically immediately closing your short sale. There would be some transaction fee loss, but minor.

Comment: Any experience writing code? Would be fairly simple to scrape the open price and execute an order based on conditional logic